# Errors while installing SQL server on linux

Tags: linux, sql-server

In order to use SQL server 2017 on linux (DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya")
 i had to install unixODBC using this line:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mssql-tools unixodbc-dev
```

But I get the following response :

```
Reading package lists ... Done
Building the dependency tree
Reading status information ... Done
Some packages can not be installed. This can mean
that you asked for the impossible, or, if you use
the unstable distribution, that some packages have not yet
were created or did not come out of Incoming.
The following information should help you resolve the situation:

The following packages contain unmet dependencies:
 mssql-tools: Depends: msodbcsql17 (> = 17.3.0.0) but will not be installed
               Depends: msodbcsql17 (<17.4.0.0) but will not be installed
 unixodbc-dev: Depends on: unixodbc (= 2.3.7)
                Depends: odbcinst1debian2 (= 2.3.7) but 2.3.1-4.1 should be installed
E: Unable to fix problems, faulty packages are in "keep as is" mode.
```

Comment: What Linux distribution is this? Linux (17.3) means kernel version, and we're decades away from 17.3.

Comment: From the version I would guess that it is Linux Mint. Could you add in your question the output of `cat /etc/sources.list`?

Comment: DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya"

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a dependency tree.

- mssql-tools needs msodbcsql17
- msodbcsql17 needs unixodbc
- unixodbc needs libodbc1

For me, installing `libodbc1` solved the issue.

```
sudo apt install libodbc1
```